# How do I get my Card (JComponent) to appear fully in my JPanel when I add it to my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

At the moment, all i see is a thin black line extending from the top left corner of the JFrame screen. I am assuming it is the bottom edge of my card and the rest is blocked from view

When i added the Card straight to the JFrame i could see all of it, so i am confused why i can only see this line (measuring the width of the card) when i add the card to the JPanel in the frame.

Code for JFrame:

```
public class WarFrame extends JFrame
{
public WarFrame()
{
    setSize(600, 800);
    setTitle("War");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    add(panel);
    panel.add(new Card(Rank.ACE));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WarFrame game = new WarFrame();
    game.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Code for Card:

```
public class Card extends JComponent
{
private final Rank rank;
private boolean faceUp;
private int x;
private int y;
private final int width;
private final int height;
private final int arcWidth;
private final int arcHeight;

public Card(Rank r)
{
    rank = r;
    faceUp = false;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    width = 75;
    height = 100;
    arcWidth = 10;
    arcHeight = 10;
}

public Card(Rank r, int x, int y)
{
    rank = r;
    faceUp = false;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    width = 75;
    height = 100;
    arcWidth = 10;
    arcHeight = 10;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D pen = (Graphics2D) g;
    //this is the black boarder
    pen.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, arcWidth, arcHeight);

    //white card body
    pen.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pen.fillRoundRect(x + 5, y + 5, width - 10, height - 10, arcWidth, arcHeight);

    if (faceUp)
    {
        //draw the card's symbol
        pen.setFont(pen.getFont().deriveFont(50f));
        pen.setColor(Color.RED);
        if (rank == Rank.TEN)
        {
            //10 has 2 digits, so needs to be shifted a bit
            pen.drawString(rank.getSymbol(), x + 5, y + 65);
        }
        else
        {
            pen.drawString(rank.getSymbol(), x + 20, y + 65);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //draw a blue rectangle as back of card pic
        pen.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        pen.fillRoundRect(x + 10, y + 10, width - 20, height - 20, arcWidth, arcHeight);
    }
}
```

I also noticed something interesting about adding the Card straight to the JFrame. The entire card shows up if painted from 0, 0

```
frame.add(new Card(Rank.ACE, 0, 0));
```

but if i add it where x > 0,

```
frame.add(new Card(Rank.ACE, 2, 10));
```

then the card starts getting cut off on the right side. Somehow when y > 0 the card is painted correctly at a lower part of the screen.

So, any suggestions why A. adding the card to a panel only makes a little line visible and 
B. when added straight to the frame, why is the card getting cut off only when x > 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` which respects the preferred size of any component added to it. When you do custom painting the default preferred size of a JComponent is (0, 0).

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` of your Card class to return the proper `Dimension` for the `Card`.

Comment: do you have any idea what is causing the card to be cutoff? I am still trying to fix that

Comment: You are hardcoding the size to be (75, 100) which is fine if you start painting at (0, 0). But if you start painting at (10, 10) then the size need to change to (85, 110). I suggestion you just always use (0, 0). Then you adjust the location of the Card to (10, 10) using the setLocation(...) method. This way painting remains constant starting at (0, 0).